# BSNL EVDO ZTE not connecting

Tags: 13.04, zte

i've a BSNL ZTE EVDO AC8700 to connect to the internet. i went to new mobile broadband. ubuntu detects my card as ZTE CDMA. i provided the necessary log in information. enabled auto connect and saved the new network.
up to ubuntu 10.10 this much was sufficient and i was able to get the internet. but in later versions, it's just connecting and connecting and showing at last "Network disconected. you are offline now."
installed ubuntu 13.04 today and same problem.
does this happen due to ubuntu's transition from Genome to unity?
pls solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The BNSL EVDO does not work by default for me too. I use it through gnome-ppp/wvdial. Please see if this helps:

Install gnome-ppp.
Run it as super user.
Give your 10 digit account-number as username AND password.
Give Phone number as #777 (I've used in Kerala and Karnataka circles).
Click on 'Setup'.
In the 'Modem' tab, click 'Detect'. The device gets detected as dev/ttyACM0.
In the 'Options' tab, along with the default options, also enable 'Ignore Terminal Strings (Stupid Mode)'.
Close the 'Setup' and try connecting now.

Also, before connecting, make sure the Modem is up. It usually takes about 30 seconds and the light stops blinking when the device is ready.